# Google sheet return how many tab are visible

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Anyone knows if there a way with a script or a formula to get the amount of visible tab or hidden tab (sheets) I can't seem to find anything on how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have go check all of the sheets and count how many are not hidden.

For example:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(sheet => !sheet.isSheetHidden()).length
```

If you're not on [V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) then use this:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(function(sheet){ return !sheet.isSheetHidden() }).length
```

Comment: I get an syntax error when using var checksheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(sheet => !sheet.isSheetHidden()).length

Comment: Are you on V8? I assumed everyone was. Let me fix the code.

Comment: should i be on V8 runtime

Comment: @YvanL It offers some nice features. I thought everyone was moved to V8 but maybe not