# Hiding 14+ sheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I ran into an issue when trying to hiding a sheets after sheet14. I can hide sheet1 through 14 but after that it just doesn't see the others when I do a mass hide or Reset. Is there a way to break the code if I have more than 14 sheets to hide/show? If not how can I do a mass hide of the sheets when C8 value ("Select Item") is met? I shortened my code below cause it is rather big, but hopefully it better shows what I'm trying to do.

```
function PatientInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Mainsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Mainsheet");
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("a");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("b");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("c");
  ↓
  var sheet29 = ss.getSheetByName("cc");

  var cell1 = Mainsheet.getRange('C8');

  if (cell1.getValue() == "Dog") {
    sheet15.showSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == "Cat") {
    sheet1.showSheet();
    sheet17.showSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == "Mouse") {
    sheet28.showSheet();
    sheet9.showheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == "Bird") {
    sheet20.showSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == "Select Item") {
    sheet1.hideSheet();
    sheet2.hideSheet();
    sheet3.hideSheet();
    ↓
    sheet29.hideSheet();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. First: one issue per question, so you'll need to split off one of your problems to a separate question. Second: "Is there a way to break the code if I have more than 14 sheets?" - you would know that there is a `hideSheet()` method [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#hidesheet) but the real issue is that YOU need to decide which sheet(s) to hide. What's your strategy for that?

Comment: @Tedinoz Sorry about the too many questions, I corrected that. I also (hopefully) explained more on the first question in my post and more of the code to illustrate. I hope it better shows what I am try to achieve.

Comment: Have you checked the execution log for errors?  Perhaps you've misspelled a sheet name in your script and it is failing at the point.

Comment: @TheWizEd I looked at the error log and it say: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hideSheet') at SelectItem(Select Item:112:13) what dose that mean?

Comment: I think you have typed the name of a sheet in your code that doesn't exist.  I don't see "SelectItem" code above.

Comment: @TheWizEd That was an error in me posting this but, you were right! I had a few spelling errors for a sheet or two and now it is FIXED! Thank you so much! i fell silly that the error was telling me to check my spelling. I will remember that!

Comment: Have you read [Google sheet return how many tab are visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60121471/1330560). It explains how to count the number of sheets that aren't hidden. You could use that value with an `if` to `break` the script.

Comment: @Tedinoz it actually turn out to be a spelling error in one of the sheets names. But this will help me in future projects, thanks!